# Data merging multiple pages with multiple text fieds in a Brochure [InDesign CC]

Tags: adobe-indesign, data-merge

I have this InDesign CC document that is a multipage brochure (15 to be exact) that has a lot of text on every page. I need to know if there's a way to switch the data in every page with data merge to create the same document with translated information in it?

How do I prepare my design for this? And how to prepare the .csv file so this won't get messy? I have 20 translations to do and ctrl-c/ctrl-v method would be really dull and unproductive.

Comment: I think you should be able to do this with Data Merge. You should be able to link each text box in ID to a text document. If you know you'll have to -update this document on a regular basis- or create similar ones in the future, then maybe it's worth it. There's also a 3rd party app called WordFlow, which links MS Word and ID. You can check it out at emSoftware.com or read about it on IndesignSecrets.com. If this is a one-off project I'd just punch through it manually.

Comment: Are your translations already in CSV or?

Comment: @Lucian No, they're merely in separate excel spreadsheets. However they are edited so badly I have to manually correct a lot of them. That's what happens when you expect professional approach from a bunch of lazy people. I decided to manually punch through it all because of those mistakes and inability to rely on scripts as for a lot of languages same parts of text can differ by too big of margin. And that combined with the mess around the data forced me to go through that with tedious, menial approach.